# Selecting records using Linq2sql into linq2sql classes?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Been succcesfully adding records using Linq2Sql with the linq2sql genereated classes, works great..

But i need to now select the records, i can't seem to figure this out

This is how i am adding records - reservation is a generated linq2sql class

```
            TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext();

            db.Reservations.InsertOnSubmit(reservation);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

So i wanted to pass in a reservation number (which is a field) a retrieve a populated Reservation class

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a strongly typed datacontext object you should be able to do something like this:

```
public Reservation GetReservation(int id) {

return db.Reservations.Where(r =>   r.ReservationId == id ).SingleOrDefault(); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks! yes that worked but my reservation class has linked object i.e. I have a class called "Calls" and a Class called "Dropped"  - both are actualy separate tables, I see properties of Count which is 1 on Calls and 3 on Dropped..  Do i need to explicitly create a calls object or something to view the details?  Thanks again

Comment: Actuall i saw there is a property called entities and under that is items but its "NOT" public..

Comment: No, as a matter of fact your Reservation object should have a propertie named Calls which is actually a list of all Calls linked to this Reservation. To get the Calls you could simply loop through each Call like this:
    foreach(Call call in Reservation.Calls) {
        //Do something with the call
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Reservation reservation = 
    db.Reservations.Where(r => r.id == reservationId).Single();
```

or

```
// Use this if you're not positive the single record exists
Reservation reservation = 
    db.Reservations.Where(r => r.id == reservationId).SingleOrDefault();
```

You can now work with `reservation` and then `db.SumbitChanges()` will save any modifications to the object back to the database.